# TIBCO checking if collection is empty jasper report dataset query

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I check if a collection parameter in dataset query is empty?

```
select country 
from counrtyTable 
where $X{IN, country,countries}
```

In my query, `countries` is a collection so how can I add a compare condition to check if that parameter is not empty or null?